# Export to Excel, how to overwrite a sheet?

Tags: ms-access

I'm wanting to automatically export my final query to excel so that I can do further work to it. The VBA code that I currently have, however, is not updating to the current query.

Example: I ran the query yesterday, it saved / exported to excel, and when I checked the excel file, it was still the previous file from yesterday but it showed that it was saved.

Here's the code:

```
Public Function ExportExcel()

    Dim myQueryName As String
    Dim myExportFileName As String


        myQueryName = "Query7"
        myExportFileName = "C:pathmumbojumbojustignore"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, myQueryName, myExportFileName, True


End Function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying new data is not included in the most recent export?

Comment: For sure you wanted to export Query8.

Comment: Make sure that *pathmumbojumbojustignore* starts with a backslash and ends with the correct filename extenseion.

Comment: @WolfgangKais The path name is correct. So what it does is it creates a brand new worksheet in the workbook instead of just overwriting the current sheet. Every. Single. Time. I don't understand.

Comment: I can't seem to read anything about a problem with worksheets in your original post. I suggest to update your question.

Comment: @WolfgangKais Updated :)

Comment: `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` always creates a new workbook file (or overwrites the existing file). It doesn't update a single sheet in an existing workbook.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have sharing/permission requirements for the generated file, delete it programatically if exists before exporting it again.